# React lazy codesplitting is including dependencies from unloaded components in the root bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I've been experimenting with React's lazy code splitting feature as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html but I'm seeing some unexpected behavior that I need help understanding and correcting.

Here is my routes file that triggers the code splitting:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const APage = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "APage" */ '../pages/APage'));
const BPage = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "BPage" */ '../pages/BPage'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/a" component={APage}/>
        <Route exact path="/b" component={BPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

When I build for production, it generates 4 files:

```
app.js    // the main bundle, includes react, react-dom, etc.
APage.js  // contains only code needed to render APage
BPage.js  // contains only code needed to render BPage
APage~BPage.js // contains components shared by APage and BPage
```

This works as expected and is able to render both routes.

However, when I add an import to my `APage` component, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { usefulFunction } from '../lib/utils';

export default class LpAPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    usefulFunction();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Landing Page A</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

The code for `usefulFunction` ends up in the main bundle (`app.js`), and it gets included in the initial load regardless of the route used.

How could I change this code so that `usefulFunction` only gets included when it is needed - in the `APage.js` chunk?

Comment: Do you import anything from `/lib/utils` elsewhere, even if it's not `usefulFunction`?

Comment: yes there is an inclusion of another utils function in the reducer which I expect to be in the main bundle. Is my issue related to this? https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#named-exports. If so, to fix, would I need to create a wrapper for every utils function?

Comment: yes, webpack's code splitting operates on modules. So, if you have a module with 100 functions, importing even a single one causes the whole module to be included in the bundle. You'd have to break up your modules to fix that.

Comment: Interesting, ok I got the behavior I wanted by moving `usefulFunction` to its own file/module

Comment: Curious if tree shaking affects this..

Comment: @bigless tree shaking will only shake modules too. Dead code elimination in the minifier might be able to remove code that is unused within modules.